# Não consigo utilizar as cores personalizadas do material ui

Tags: react, typescript, button, material-ui

criei um tema customizado do material UI com uma paleta de cores própria. Porém na hora de consumir esta paleta em um button na propriedade color o typescript da erro.

Theme:

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core'

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    gray: Palette['primary']
    light: Palette['primary']
    dark: Palette['primary']
    bgColor: Palette['primary']
    fontColor: Palette['primary']
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    gray: PaletteOptions['primary']
    light: PaletteOptions['primary']
    dark: PaletteOptions['primary']
    bgColor: PaletteOptions['primary']
    fontColor: PaletteOptions['primary']
  }
}

const mainTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      50: '#e5f7ff',
      100: '#b8e8ff',
      200: '#8ad9ff',
      300: '#5ccaff',
      400: '#2ebbff',
      500: '#00acff',
      600: '#008acc',
      700: '#006799',
      800: '#004566',
      900: '#002233',
      main: '#00acff'
    },
    gray: {
      50: '#f0f1f4',
      100: '#d6d9e0',
      200: '#bcc0cd',
      300: '#a2a7b9',
      400: '#888ea5',
      500: '#6e7691',
      600: '#585e74',
      700: '#424757',
      800: '#2c2f3a',
      900: '#16181d',
      main: '#6e7691'
    },
    light: {
      main: '#f0f1f4'
    },
    dark: {
      main: '#585e74'
    },
    bgColor: {
      main: '#f5f8fb'
    },
    fontColor: {
      main: '#6e7691'
    }
  }
})

export { mainTheme }
```

Em outro arquivo

```
import { NavbarContainer } from './styles'

import { FiCalendar, FiLogIn, FiTrello, FiVolumeX } from 'react-icons/fi'
import {
  Toolbar,
  Container,
  Link,
  Box,
  Button,
  Typography,
  ThemeProvider
} from '@material-ui/core'

import { mainTheme } from '../../styles/themes'

export const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
        <Button href="#" color="primary" startIcon={<FiTrello />}>
            <span>Catálogo</span>
        </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Erro exibido:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; endIcon?: ReactNode; ... 4 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '"palette.dark"' is not assignable to type '"default" | "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary"'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '"palette.dark"' is not assignable to type 'Color'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '"palette.dark"' is not assignable to type 'Color'.ts(2769)
Button.d.ts(17, 5): The expected type comes from property 'color' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: boolean; disableFocusRipple?: boolean; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 1 more ... | "contained"; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Precisa mencionar qual opção da primary color. Ex: (primary.main)

```
<Button href="#" color="primary.main" startIcon={<FiTrello />}>
            <span>Catálogo</span>
</Button>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).